# How to control Retained Size memory?

Tags: javascript, flask, memory-leaks

[image: Memory in Chrome(image)]

I'm using flask. But memory leak occur.How can I control the Retained Size memory?(gvjs.5l,Object etc..)
I tried several method.

1. used del in flask.(ex del var_name)
2. allocated null in javascript (ex var_name = null;)
3. used gc(garbage collect) in flask.(gc.collect())

Is there any way?

[EDIT]
[Python code(garbage collect)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlBir.png)

Comment: The memory usage in Chrome does not have anything to do with your Python code.

Comment: Edited my post.

Comment: You misunderstood me. I'm saying that your issue is not in your Python code, must be a Javascript issue or a Chrome bug.